# Find the value of $ \sum_{r = 0}^{10}(1-2r)^{10}C_r $

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, combinations

$$
\sum_{r = 0}^{10}(1-2r)^{10}C_r
$$
where $^{10}C_r$ are binomial coefficients. How to find the value of above expression?

Is there any trick for such type of problems?

Comment: Does $^{10}$ belong to $(1-2r)$, and in that case what is $C_r$? Or does $^{10}$ belong to the $C$, and in that case, is it the so-called "choose function", the binomial coefficients (in other words $^{10}C_r$)?

Comment: @Arthur the second case , binomial coefficient

Comment: Did you mean $\sum\limits_{r = 0}^{10}(1-2r)\cdot\binom{10}{r}$?

Comment: @barakmanos yeah you are right

Comment: Well then you could simply calculate it ([or let WolframAlpha do it for you](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Br%3D0%7D%5E%7B10%7D(1-2r)%5Ccdot%5Cbinom%7B10%7D%7Br%7D)). In any case, the answer is $-9216$.

Comment: @barakmanos but how to calculate manually

Comment: I have a solution also , but I could not understand . What they have done.

Comment: Well, $(1-2)\cdot\binom{10}{1}+(1-4)\cdot\binom{10}{2}+(1-6)\cdot\binom{10}{3}+\ldots+(1-20)\cdot\binom{10}{10}$.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/9ynZEOV.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{r = 0}^{10}(1-2r)\cdot\binom{10}{r}$$
$$=\sum_{r = 0}^{10}\binom{10}{r} - 2\sum_{r = 0}^{10}r\cdot\binom{10}{r} $$

Now, we know, by Binomial Theorem, that
$$(1+x)^{10}=\sum_{r = 0}^{10}\binom{10}{r}x^r$$
Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$, we get
 $$10(1+x)^{9}=\sum_{r = 0}^{10}r\cdot\binom{10}{r}x^{r-1}$$
Putting $x=1$, we get
$$10(1+1)^{9}=\sum_{r = 0}^{10}r\cdot\binom{10}{r}1^{r-1}$$
$$\boxed{\sum_{r = 0}^{10}r\cdot\binom{10}{r}=10\cdot2^{9}}$$
Therefore, we get that
$$\sum_{r = 0}^{10}(1-2r)\cdot\binom{10}{r}$$
$$=\sum_{r = 0}^{10}\binom{10}{r} - 2\sum_{r = 0}^{10}r\cdot\binom{10}{r} $$
$$=2^{10}-2\cdot10\cdot2^{9}$$
$$\boxed{\sum_{r = 0}^{10}(1-2r)\cdot\binom{10}{r}=-9\cdot 2^{10}}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have:
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{r=0}^{10}r\binom{10}{r} &=\sum_{r=1}^{10}r\binom{10}{r} \\ &= \sum_{r=1}^{10}r\frac{10!}{r!(10-r)!} \\&=\sum_{r=1}^{10}(11-r)\frac{10!}{(r-1)!(11-r)!} \\&=\sum_{r=0}^{9}(10-r)\binom{10}{r}
 \\&=\sum_{r=0}^{10}(10-r)\binom{10}{r} \\&=10\sum_{r=0}^{10}\binom{10}{r} - \sum_{r=0}^{10}r\binom{10}{r} \\&= 10\cdot2^{10} - \sum_{r=0}^{10}r\binom{10}{r}
 \end{aligned}$$
So therefore:
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{r=0}^{10}(1-2r)\binom{10}{r} =\sum_{r=0}^{10}\binom{10}{r} - 2\sum_{r=0}^{10}r\binom{10}{r} = 2^{10} - 10\cdot2^{10} = -9\cdot 2^{10}
 \end{aligned}$$